# Sort nested lists by the first element in lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to sort nested lists based on the first element in each list...

So I have the following:

```
 input = [['ABCMeter', 'six', 'page','car=frog'],['ABCarrow','mall','cop''xmlVal'],['ABCcomp','eleven','computer'],['ABCliz','one']]
```

I need them sorted such that:

```
output = [['ABCarrow','mall','cop''xmlVal'], ['ABCcomp','eleven','computer'], ['ABCliz','one'], ['ABCMeter', 'six', 'page','car=frog']]
```

I have tried the following with no luck (and several other sort methods):

```
split_into_lists = input.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
```

Answer (score 3):

You are just using the wrong function; the `sort` method modifies the list in-place and returns `None`. Use `sorted` instead to return a new list.

```
split_into_lists = sorted(input, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

Comment: Or just call `.sort` without assigning the return value and use the original `list`. I'll note that the `key` argument isn't necessary if the first element of each `list` is unique, or if you're okay with comparisons falling back to the second, third, etc. elements in case of a tie; `list`s compare lexicographically, so it already prioritizes comparing by first element, and only checks subsequent elements when the first elements are equal.

Answer (score 2):

Also, the expected output doesn't match the sort criteria of String objects.

For example:
`ABCMeter` < `ABCarrow`

It compares character by character, and if they are equal, it compares the next one. Since `M` is less than `a` (see ASCII Table), `ABCMeter` < `ABCarrow`

Answer (score 2):

```
split_into_lists = sorted(input, key=lambda x: x[0].casefold())
```